# Hide checkbox in OO BASIC

Tags: openoffice-calc, openoffice-basic

Hi
How I can hide check box in Open Office BASIC? I tried use:

```
chckbox.visible=false
```

but it doesn`t work.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So checkbox has no Visible Property only `EnableVisible=True/False`

It should helps

have a nice day[image]